# ArnoPro font loading in xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, opentype

I am new to XeLaTeX, I want to typeset in ArnoPro font, when I am using the fontsize 10pt xeLaTeX automaticaly load the Font ArnoPro-smText instead of ArnoPro-Regular.

The same problem is coming for bold and italic fonts, when I am using the fontsize 11, then ArnoPro-Regular font is loading, but I need to typeset in 10pt. How to laod the ArnoPro-Regular, ArnoPro-Bold font in Xelatex?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={Arno Pro Italic},
             BoldFont={Arno Pro Bold},
             BoldItalicFont={Arno Pro Bold Italic}
             ]{Arno Pro}
\begin{document}
Sample text \textit{itshape} | \textsc{Small caps} | \textsc{\textit{Small caps Italic}} | \textbf{Bold} | \textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without knowing the font, it seems that Arno Pro comes in various optical sizes, so it chooses a more appropriate font when you use a small type size.

Comment: It seems to be the norm for `8.6–11pt` font size, according to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21297/how-should-fontspec-be-set-up-to-exploit-the-best-features-of-pro-fonts). I've test and indeed with option `12pt`, it is `Arno Pro Regular` that is loaded.

Comment: I also tried that same but I need the 10 pt with Arno Pro Regula

Comment: I don’t have Arno Pro for testing, but setting the `OpticalSize` option to 0, as shown in example 16 on page 21 of the manual for `fontspec`, should do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

In 2018 4Q, i.e., three years after the Q, you're likely no longer new to `xelatex`, and  you may have long since come to a suitable resolution. Others facing this same (type of) question may benefit from these details.

Since the focus in the question and for a reliable solution, per the concept taught early and often by Ulrike Fischer, *e.g.,* in this [font question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18037/170846), among others, is in the fontname, it's worth the time to address this in the `xelatex`-specific context, per the Q.

The code that follows demonstrates both font size and font name/style, so as to confirm that the generic font name identified in the MWE's `\setmainfont` is, in fact, the specific font used by `xelatex` for all three standard book class font sizes (10pt, 11pt (10.95pt), and 12pt).  Given the number of possible Arno-Pro font faces, there's a substantial need to eliminate the other possibilities. (Of course, the surest method is to have installed only the font face of choice. Thus, the implied context of the Q, here, is that of proper selection from among those multiple choices.)

The MWE defines `{Arno Pro}`, expecting that `ArnoPro-Regular.otf` is what the system will use, yet the OP's system was using `ArnoPro-SmText.otf`, instead.  On this system (MacTeX, TexLive 2016), `xelatex` sees `{Arno Pro}` in the `\setmainfont` command and uses `ArnoPro-Regular.otf` for all three standard book class normal font sizes.  To see this specifically, scroll to the end of the xelatex-produced .pdf of the code below to see that the "Sample text" output, based on `{Arno Pro}`, is identical to the `\ArnoProThrZro` output. `ArnoProThrZro` is constructed on the `ArnoPro-Regular.otf` fontfamily. The "Sample text" does not match the `ArnoProThrOne` output, which is constructed on the `ArnoPro-SmText.otf` fonts. *See* sample output segment following code.

Would that it were so simple.  Font selection, even with `xelatex`, takes some care in the details, including appreciation of how `xelatex` goes about making that decision. A concept to share about how *this* system is (now) set up, the `OSFONTDIR` path setting is commented out in this system's `.bash_profile` file (in some systems, it's the  `.profile` file, which seems to depend on which shell one has or is accustomed to using). While `xelatex` is designed to access the system's font files (and "system font" font files as well, of course) via use of the OSFONTDIR path(s) and use them by the simplicity of the font name, `xelatex` is also (still) insistent on the "one and only one font definition" concept. Thus, where `xelatex` reviews all the `OSFONTDIR` path(s) and finds a font definition and a font suitcase or, e.g., both a `.ttf` definition and a `.otf` definition, `xelatex` can have troubles identifying the font(s) by a generic name. To eliminate that possibility completely (who has the time to chase these font issues constantly?), `OSFONTDIR` is not used, at all, and the fonts are installed manually into the texlive tree structure, `.ttf` files into their set of directories (folders), e.g., `/fonts/truetype/<various font files>`, and `.otf` files into their set of directories (folders), e.g., `/fonts/opentype/<various font files>`.  It can take several minutes to set up those directories in the texlive tree, which minutes save hours and hours (*and hours,* etc.) on the back end. [When adding a new font to the texlive tree structure, remember to (A) (sudo) -H mktexlsr  [(sudo) -H texhash] and (B) (sudo) fc-cache -fv.]  Also, in the .tex file, use of the actual font filename with its extension is (now) the coding practice "here" where `xelatex` is the intended compiling engine.

Shouldn't have to do that for `xelatex`. One "convenience" and advancement of `xelatex` is the use of installed fonts "as is."  And, as this very example shows, that level of font specification isn't necessary on this system. "Here," `xelatex` knows exactly which font is meant by `{Arno Pro}`. However, that is due to the "one definition" of the font by there being only one definition (in part because the only place `xelatex` is looking is in the tree structure, which very greatly increases the likelihood of there being just "one definition").

Bottom line, the following shows that where the desired font(s) is(are) installed in such a way as to be found uniquely by `xelatex`, the MWE should work just fine to accomplish the stated purpose of using `ArnoPro-Regular` instead of `ArnoPro-SmText`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
%https://www.wfonts.com/font/arno-pro
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={Arno Pro Italic},
             BoldFont={Arno Pro Bold},
             BoldItalicFont={Arno Pro Bold Italic}
             ]{Arno Pro}

%borrowing from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24600/170846
\makeatletter
\newcommand\thefontsize[1]{{#1 The current font size is: \f@size pt\par}}
\makeatother

%borrowing from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87908/170846
\newenvironment{localsize}[1]
{%
%  \clearpage
    \par
    \let\orignewcommand\newcommand
    \let\newcommand\renewcommand
    \makeatletter
    \input{bk#1.clo}%  possible values for book.cls: 10, 11, 12
    \makeatother
    \let\newcommand\orignewcommand
}
{%
  %\clearpage
  \par
}


% borrowing from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255384/170846
% and from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37251/170846
\newfontfamily\ArnoProZroOne{ArnoPro-Regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProZroTwo{ArnoPro-SmText.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProZroThr{ArnoPro-Italic.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProZroFor{ArnoPro-ItalicSmText.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProZroFiv{ArnoPro-Bold.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProZroSix{ArnoPro-BoldItalic.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProZroSvn{ArnoPro-Smbd.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProZroAte{ArnoPro-SmbdSmText.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProZroNin{ArnoPro-SmbdItalicSmText.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProOneZro{ArnoPro-Caption.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProOneOne{ArnoPro-ItalicCaption.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProOneTwo{ArnoPro-BoldCaption.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProOneThr{ArnoPro-SmbdItalicCaption.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProOneFor{ArnoPro-Subhead.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProOneFiv{ArnoPro-ItalicSubhead.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProOneSix{ArnoPro-BoldSubhead.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProOneSvn{ArnoPro-BoldItalicSubhead.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProOneAte{ArnoPro-SmbdSubhead.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProOneNin{ArnoPro-SmbdItalicSubhead.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProTwoZro{ArnoPro-Display.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProTwoOne{ArnoPro-ItalicDisplay.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProTwoTwo{ArnoPro-LightDisplay.otf}
\newfontfamily\ArnoProTwoThr{ArnoPro-LightItalicDisplay.otf}

\newfontfamily\ArnoProThrZro[ItalicFont=ArnoPro-Italic.otf,
             BoldFont=ArnoPro-Bold.otf,
             BoldItalicFont=ArnoPro-BoldItalic.otf
             ]{ArnoPro-Regular.otf}

\newfontfamily\ArnoProThrOne[%
    ItalicFont={ArnoPro-ItalicSmText.otf}
    ]{ArnoPro-SmText.otf}


\begin{document}
\doublespacing

% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14376/170846
\thefontsize\normalsize

%borrowing from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307369/170846
\expandafter\string\the\font

\begin{localsize}{10}

\parindent 0in

\thefontsize\normalsize

Sample text at 10pt

\expandafter\string\the\font

\textit{itshape \expandafter\string\the\font} 

\textsc{Small caps \expandafter\string\the\font} 

\textsc{\textit{Small caps Italic \expandafter\string\the\font}} 

\textbf{Bold \expandafter\string\the\font} 

\textbf{\textit{Bold Italic \expandafter\string\the\font}}

\end{localsize}

\begin{localsize}{11}

\parindent 0in

\thefontsize\normalsize

Sample text at 11pt

\expandafter\string\the\font

\textit{itshape \expandafter\string\the\font} 

\textsc{Small caps \expandafter\string\the\font} 

\textsc{\textit{Small caps Italic \expandafter\string\the\font}} 

\textbf{Bold \expandafter\string\the\font} 

\textbf{\textit{Bold Italic \expandafter\string\the\font}}

\end{localsize}

\begin{localsize}{12}

\parindent 0in

\thefontsize\normalsize

Sample text at 12pt

\expandafter\string\the\font

\textit{itshape \expandafter\string\the\font} 

\textsc{Small caps \expandafter\string\the\font} 

\textsc{\textit{Small caps Italic \expandafter\string\the\font}} 

\textbf{Bold \expandafter\string\the\font} 

\textbf{\textit{Bold Italic \expandafter\string\the\font}}

\end{localsize}

\singlespacing

\begin{localsize}{10}
\parindent 0in

Font set at 10pt

\ArnoProZroOne{ArnoPro-Regular.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroTwo{ArnoPro-SmText.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroThr{ArnoPro-Italic.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroFor{ArnoPro-ItalicSmText.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroFiv{ArnoPro-Bold.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroSix{ArnoPro-BoldItalic.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroSvn{ArnoPro-Smbd.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroAte{ArnoPro-SmbdSmText.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroNin{ArnoPro-SmbdItalicSmText.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneZro{ArnoPro-Caption.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneOne{ArnoPro-ItalicCaption.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneTwo{ArnoPro-BoldCaption.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneThr{ArnoPro-SmbdItalicCaption.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneFor{ArnoPro-Subhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneFiv{ArnoPro-ItalicSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneSix{ArnoPro-BoldSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneSvn{ArnoPro-BoldItalicSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneAte{ArnoPro-SmbdSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneNin{ArnoPro-SmbdItalicSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProTwoZro{ArnoPro-Display.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProTwoOne{ ArnoPro-ItalicDisplay.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProTwoTwo{ArnoPro-LightDisplay.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProTwoThr{ArnoPro-LightItalicDisplay.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\end{localsize}
\par 

\begin{localsize}{11}
\parindent 0in

Font set at 11pt

\ArnoProZroOne{ArnoPro-Regular.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroTwo{ArnoPro-SmText.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroThr{ArnoPro-Italic.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroFor{ArnoPro-ItalicSmText.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroFiv{ArnoPro-Bold.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroSix{ArnoPro-BoldItalic.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroSvn{ArnoPro-Smbd.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroAte{ArnoPro-SmbdSmText.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroNin{ArnoPro-SmbdItalicSmText.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneZro{ArnoPro-Caption.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneOne{ArnoPro-ItalicCaption.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneTwo{ArnoPro-BoldCaption.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneThr{ArnoPro-SmbdItalicCaption.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneFor{ArnoPro-Subhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneFiv{ArnoPro-ItalicSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneSix{ArnoPro-BoldSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneSvn{ArnoPro-BoldItalicSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneAte{ArnoPro-SmbdSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneNin{ArnoPro-SmbdItalicSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProTwoZro{ArnoPro-Display.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProTwoOne{ ArnoPro-ItalicDisplay.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProTwoTwo{ArnoPro-LightDisplay.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProTwoThr{ArnoPro-LightItalicDisplay.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\end{localsize}
\par

\begin{localsize}{12}
\parindent 0in

Font set at 12pt

\ArnoProZroOne{ArnoPro-Regular.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroTwo{ArnoPro-SmText.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroThr{ArnoPro-Italic.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroFor{ArnoPro-ItalicSmText.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroFiv{ArnoPro-Bold.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroSix{ArnoPro-BoldItalic.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroSvn{ArnoPro-Smbd.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroAte{ArnoPro-SmbdSmText.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProZroNin{ArnoPro-SmbdItalicSmText.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneZro{ArnoPro-Caption.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneOne{ArnoPro-ItalicCaption.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneTwo{ArnoPro-BoldCaption.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneThr{ArnoPro-SmbdItalicCaption.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneFor{ArnoPro-Subhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneFiv{ArnoPro-ItalicSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneSix{ArnoPro-BoldSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneSvn{ArnoPro-BoldItalicSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneAte{ArnoPro-SmbdSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProOneNin{ArnoPro-SmbdItalicSubhead.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProTwoZro{ArnoPro-Display.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProTwoOne{ ArnoPro-ItalicDisplay.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProTwoTwo{ArnoPro-LightDisplay.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\ArnoProTwoThr{ArnoPro-LightItalicDisplay.otf:\\ The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\end{localsize}

\bigskip

\begin{localsize}{10}
\parindent 0in

Sample text in 10pt  \textit{Italics} | \textsc{Small caps} | \textsc{\textit{Small caps Italic}} | \textbf{Bold} | \textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}}

\ArnoProThrZro{Sample text ThrZro \textit{Italics} | \textsc{Small caps} | \textsc{\textit{Small caps Italic}} | \textbf{Bold} | \textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}}
}

\ArnoProThrOne{Sample text ThrOne \textit{Italics} | \textsc{Small caps} | \textsc{\textit{Small caps Italic}} | \textbf{Bold} | \textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}}
}

\end{localsize}

\begin{localsize}{11}
\parindent 0in

Sample text in 11pt  \textit{Italics} | \textsc{Small caps} | \textsc{\textit{Small caps Italic}} | \textbf{Bold} | \textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}}

\ArnoProThrZro{Sample text ThrZro \textit{Italics} | \textsc{Small caps} | \textsc{\textit{Small caps Italic}} | \textbf{Bold} | \textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}}
}

\ArnoProThrOne{Sample text ThrOne \textit{Italics} | \textsc{Small caps} | \textsc{\textit{Small caps Italic}} | \textbf{Bold} | \textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}}
}

\end{localsize}

\begin{localsize}{12}
\parindent 0in

Sample text in 12pt  \textit{Italics} | \textsc{Small caps} | \textsc{\textit{Small caps Italic}} | \textbf{Bold} | \textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}}

\ArnoProThrZro{Sample text ThrZro \textit{Italics} | \textsc{Small caps} | \textsc{\textit{Small caps Italic}} | \textbf{Bold} | \textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}}
}

\ArnoProThrOne{Sample text ThrOne \textit{Italics} | \textsc{Small caps} | \textsc{\textit{Small caps Italic}} | \textbf{Bold} | \textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}}
}

\end{localsize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Confirmation for all three font sizes]

Answer (score 2):

Define the `UprightFont`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{ArnoPro}[
  UprightFont   = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont    = *-Italic,
  BoldFont      = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont= *-BoldItalic
]
\begin{document}
    Sample text \textit{itshape} | \textsc{Small caps} | \textsc{\textit{Small caps Italic}} | 
    \textbf{Bold} | \textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}}
\end{document}
```

[image]